# How to set a capability to open a keyboard in iOS real devices in appium testing?

Tags: ios, macos, selenium, safari, appium

I'm testing the web application on safari browser in iOS Devices.,
Here there is a scenario like entering the product quantity in text box. 
For that i used `Element.Sendkeys("Qauntity");`
After entering the quantity automatically added the count into shopping bag,
But it is not working in iOS Devices. (It is working fine in Windows Desktop Browsers).

After entering the quantity in text box 
/*My Code to enter text and hit enter */

```
    Element.Sendkeys("Qauntity"); //It is typing
    Element.Sendkeys(Keys.Enter); //Doesn't Enter
    Element.Sendkeys(Keys.Tab);   //Doesn't Tab
```

How to solve this??

Is there any way to Open a iOS Keyboard like passing desired     capabilities(Unicode Keyboard for android) ?

Thanks in advance!